# Copy data from one .exe to another in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

In my client computer already contain an executable program and is always at the running mode.

Now I need to generate a new c# program to copy the all data from the running executable program in my client computer.

So, how to copy data from one program to another program?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Are you asking how to write two programs that communicate with eachother? If so, look at WCF.

Comment: Are you wanting to extract data from the executable binary? From memory?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit vague, but one idea is to host a service in the existing executable that you can call from the other application to access the data. You can do something simple like either self hosted WEB API or WCF

Resources here here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

Another option is making use of message queuing to communicate

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, these 2 example is to access data from a web, and what I want is to access data from another .exe program to another .exe program.

Comment: It will do that. The point is that you host the service inside the executable program.